# Does GoogleAppIndex really indexes the content of the app?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

Im trying to understand Google's docs about GoogleAppIndex and I don't understand how it really works.
https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/introduction
In the introduction they say "make content within your app"
Do they really read the content after implementing universal links and Google app index api?
Or is it only "this webpage is this app page"?

Answer (score 2):

No, Google App Indexing does not index the content.

When you define the website:app association, Google indexes the URLs of your website based in the intents defined in your Manifest.xml, verifying if the website URLs are supported by the App and present content.

As it is said in the documentation "Google automatically starts indexing any existing or new URLs to your app. Our systems use URLs discovered through web indexing that match the intent-filter patterns in your AndroidManifest.xml file." - https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app#declare-a-website-association

Also, the Google App Indexing API only indexes the title and description (if defined) that you define in the API calls. You have more information on this here - https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish#add-app-indexing-api-calls

Comment: Thank you. What about ios? Does it also index the title /description ?

Comment: Google App Indexing in iOS is based in the Universal Links implementation.
You just need to add the App Indexing SDK and register your app.

You have more information here: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/ios/server

Comment: Yes, I have read all the google docs, but im not sure i understand. In another post, i can see that you say that Google DOES index the content.. Could you be clearer please? :). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496961

Comment: What I meant there by content was the title and description. With the API implemented in your app, if an user explores or opens your app from a deep link, the next time the user performs a new Search similar to previous opened content, the auto-suggestion will come into use and present the user with that previously opened content (title&description).

Comment: Are you talking about android only? or iOS too? cause in iOS, the documentation doesnt talk about title and description

Comment: I'm talking about Android. For iOS you need to verify Apple Universal Links documentation.

Comment: @StanCt Apple Universal Links documentation doesn't answer the question